# Bind multiple <option> values to model in the order they appear using asp-for tag helper

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, data-binding, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.2

I have a custom control (see picture below). My goal is to retrieve items from the selected (in oragne rectangle) list on POST action. However the order of the items matters.
[image]

Below is an example of the select list:

```
<select class="target-list-items assign-list valid" asp-for="FinallyAssignedFields" multiple="multiple" size="10" data-field-name="FinallyAssignedFields" aria-invalid="false">
    <option value="100" data-guid="53dc9ed8-5b8d-48de-9aba-26bc7930053d">Article_CustomTextField6</option>
    <option value="107" data-guid="29c55f83-a136-4238-a64c-1d94c3833b2b">Article_DCLocation1</option>
    <option value="132" data-guid="8b89a96a-0b09-4ab3-81f5-58a309e63676">Article_ExpireDayTue</option>     
    <option value="134" data-guid="4b46d48e-cd02-4f14-a8e0-5d54aef55ae2">Article_ExtraTender</option>
    <option value="104" data-guid="ddb35db6-b4a1-40dc-b6b1-47528cff9faa">Article_CuttingTypeID</option>
    <option value="129" data-guid="7c1917bd-6baa-4949-98c5-87d49375d55c">Article_ExpireDaySat</option>  
    <option value="174" data-guid="224dcc64-f83a-4d6c806a6a2d29955918">Article_MaxPortionWeight</option>
    <option value="169" data-guid="b49165e6-4f94-4248-9ba9-482887105cb2">Article_LastFlashedUB</option> 
    <option value="204" data-guid="766f90d5-a11e-414e-9f6ea568ca9b60d7">Article_OverProductionFri</option>
    <option value="173" data-guid="805f0009-db9f-4610bd03-4cce089f6f72">Article_MaxIncompleteCratesCount</option>
    <option value="201" data-guid="f2242143-ed82-4373-be65-99fa3fde38b7">Article_OtherInformation</option>
</select>
```

Here is my view model:

```
public class DepartmentArticleFieldGroupViewModel : IDepartmentArticleFieldGroupModel, IReturnableViewModel
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public string GroupName { get; set; }
    public int OrderNo { get; set; }

    public List<DepartmentArticleFieldGroupFieldViewModel> Fields { get; set; }
    public SelectList AvailableFields { get; set; }
    public SelectList InitiallyAssignedFields { get; set; }
    public int[] FinallyAssignedFields { get; set; }  // <---- I want to bind selected items to this

    public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }
}
```

`select` element above has `asp-for="FinallyAssignedFields"` tag and I can see the values inside my `HttpPost` method, however obtained values appear not in the order they are in HTML, but they are sorted ascending. **Is it a default behavior?**

[image]

I've searched a lot of articles and forums, but couldn't find anything helpful. **Is it possible to disable this sorting on binding multiple values using `asp-for`? If not - is there any clean way to bind these values without any workarounds?** I mean to have information: first item = 100, second one = 107, 3rd = 132, 4th = 132, 5th =104 and so on..?

I'd be thankful for any hint!

Comment: Are you certain it isn't the browser doing the sorting? Either way I would encode the order separately. Perhaps as a json blob in a hidden form field.

Comment: With your sample `select` having `size=10` why is your picture showing so many more?

Comment: *obtained values appear not in the order they are in HTML* : I'm pretty sure that ASP.NET Core won't sort it by default. My best guess is : that is related to your **client control** (seems you're using a select control that supports adjust the order of <options> ? ). Please **check the payload sent to the server** (by pressing `F12` in browser) and make sure the fields order in the HTTP POST request is  correct.